# How to push website content down, to insert content above, when fixed position element is used in body

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to add slide-down content block above the website content. Slide-down block should pus all website content down for the height of the content inside slide-down block. Unfortunately, when using Twitter Bootstrap with affixed header, it's not possible to achieve this since fixed position elements don't move when content is added above them.

I'm using simple jQuery slideDown function to slide content down. This is simplified markup example:

```
<body>
    <div class="slide-down">slide content</div>
    <div class="fixed-position-header">header</div>
    <div class="main-content">
        <div class="fixed-position-sidebar">sidebar</div>
        <div class="main-content">main-content</div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">footer</div>
</body>
```

Anyone has an idea how this could be achieved? Javascript or some clever CSS hack?

Comment: Use your jQuery script to animate the header and sidebar down at the same time

Comment: I'm thinking about that, and it looks like only solution at this moment, but I was hoping someone have already done something similar and might share some tips of suggest more elegant way of doing it.

Comment: There's no way with CSS to push a fixed or absolutely positioned element anywhere.  (of course absolute could be pushed if it were inside a relative document that moves)

Answer (score 0):

You would just add some lines in your jQuery that will animate your header and sidebar down at the same time.

```
$('.button').click(function(){
    $('.fixed-position-header, .fixed-position-sidebar').animate({top: '50px'});
});
```

Of course you would have to add some more logic to make sure it animates back upwards and make sure the top value is similar to the slide-down height value.

Answer (score 0):

Are you adding the block, or are you just displaying it?

If you're adding it, you can provision your `.fixed-position-header` with:

```
.slide-down ~ .fixed-position-header {
    transition: .5s top ease;
    top: 50px;
}
```

If you're just displaying it, when you display it, do so with a class, and then style accordingly.

```
$('.slide-down').addClass('active');
```

CSS:

```
.slide-down {
    display: none;
}
.slide-down.active {
    display: block;
}
.slide-down.active ~ .fixed-position-header {
    transition: .5s top ease;
    top: 50px;
}
```